# TypeError: Cannot read property '-KzhZRTUYIXTdH0Zgxz4' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I'm getting a funny error and I don't know where it's coming from.
I've gone through the code and haven't been able to continue

This is the ProductCard.component.ts

```js
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from '../model/product';
import {ShoppingCartService} from '../shopping-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('product') product: Product;
    @Input('showActions') showActions = true;
    @Input('shoppingCart') shoppingCart;
  constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  }
  getQuantity() {
    if (!this.shoppingCart) {return 0; }
    const item = this.shoppingCart.items[this.product.$key];
    return item ? item.quantity : 0;
  }
}

This is the ProductCard.component.html
```

```html
<div *ngIf="product.title" class="card">
  <img *ngIf="product.imageUrl" class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.imageUrl}}" alt="{{ product.title}}">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.title}}</h4>
    <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency:'NGN':true}}</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="showActions" class="card-footer">
    <button
      *ngIf="getQuantity() === 0; else updateQuantity"
        (click)="addToCart(product)"
      class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
    <ng-template #updateQuantity>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{getQuantity()}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Error i get from the chrome dev Console

```js
ProductCardComponent.ngfactory.js:53 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '-KzhZRTUYIXTdH0Zgxz4' of undefined
    at ProductCardComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/product-card/product-card.component.ts.ProductCardComponent.getQuantity (main.bundle.js:1293)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProductCardComponent.ngfactory.js:60)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:109317)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:108501)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:108849)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:108807)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:108502)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:108849)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:108807)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:108502)
```

if you want to check the whole code [This the link to my repo on github](https://github.com/Tooluloope/Noodles-Hub)

Comment: `shoppingCart.items` is `undefined`

Comment: `this.shoppingCart.items` is not defined, and I can't find `shopping-cart.service` in your girhub repo

Comment: its in the Import

Comment: The error you get is because you can't access ID in your firebase

Comment: shopping cart service is now in the repo

Comment: Yes i cant access the ID in firebase

Comment: You are trything to get single product id. Can you console.log(this.product.$key) this should be undefined.

Comment: @stojevskimilan I didn't get undefined, it actually got the product Id of all the products

Comment: @JoeFrambach how is it not defined? Please I'm actually a newbie to angular

Comment: Can you move  `const item = this.shoppingCart.items[this.product.$key];` to `ngOnInit`

Comment: what would happen to the remaining code block in getQuantity() @stojevskimilan

Comment: console.log(item) in your method and then comment your method and move the code to ngOnInit and console.log(item)

Comment: The error still shows @stojevskimilan

Comment: I've found the error, its meant to be  @Input('shopping-carts') shoppingCart;

Answer (score 0):

```
const item = this.shoppingCart.items[this.product.$key];
```

this line causes the error because the key is deleted so you have to erase it manually from the local storage also from firebase and create new cart;

Answer (score 0):

Here was required a change in products.component.ts I had to add .valueChanges()

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = (await this.shoppingCartService.getCart())
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((cart) => (this.cart = cart));
}
```